# Two JOINS from same Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, select

I have two tables **Document** and **Xref**.

**Xref** is a means of linking a document to another document.

The **Xref Table** stores the **id** of the **documen**t (from the documents table) and it's linked **xref** (also from the documents table)

I want to retrieve a list of **filenames** for the **Xrefs** that are linked to a particular **Document**.

Please see attached image for a basic representation of my Tables.

The following SQL statement retrieves the (xref)filename I want, but I want to be able to use the filename not it's id to retrieve this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: There is no SQL in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to JOIN both table. This should do it :

```
SELECT d.filename
FROM 
    Document d
    INNER JOIN Xref x ON x.xref_id = d.id
WHERE x.document_id = ?
```

You want to replace the question mark with the id of the document whose filename you want to find.

If you want to search by document name instead of document id then you need one more JOIN :

```
SELECT d.filename
FROM 
    Document d
    INNER JOIN Xref x ON x.xref_id = d.id
    INNER JOIN Document d2 ON d2.id = x.document_id
WHERE d2.filename = ?
```

NB : this assumes that every document has a linked document in table Xref. If you want NOT to filter out documents without Xref, you want to use « LEFT JOIN » instead of « INNER JOIN ».

Comment: Thank you for the response, this wants to use the "id" as per my example, but I don't know the "id" I know the filename.

Comment: Thanks again for your response and time. Unfortunately this doesn't retrieve a result, similar to my attempts...

Comment: Apologies I mixed up my filenames. This retrieves exactly what I want. Thank you very much for your time and response. It really is appreciated.

Comment: NOTE: If a document doesn't have a linked document in `xref`, then an `INNER JOIN` will exclude the main document.

Comment: @Shawn : that’s right. I updated my answer to be specific about this point.

Answer (score 2):

Join twice against Xref, once to get the ref file filename and once to search on filename for main document

```
SELECT d2.filename
FROM Document d
JOIN Xref x ON d.id = x.document_id
JOIN Document d2 ON d2.id = x.xref_id
WHERE d.name = ?
```

---

For example

```
SELECT d2.filename
FROM Document d
JOIN Xref x ON d.id = x.document_id
JOIN Document d2 ON d2.id = x.xref_id
WHERE d.name = 'D001'
```

returns

> filename
>   X001

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this didn't retrieve anything...

Comment: @squatman This works fine for me when replacing the ? with both 'D001' and 'D002', where I get X001 as the result both times.

Comment: Ah yes, my apologies. I had mixed the id column with the retrieved row id of my query. Thank you very much for your help and time. It really is appreciated.

Comment: Actually, this still doesn't retrieve anything, it was one of the other answers that did.

Comment: @squatman, I now see I had a typo, id instead of document_id. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

You need to SELECT your main data and then use the JOIN on some field or column.

LEFT JOIN will keep data from the left group.

INNER JOIN will result with the matches only.

Need to make sure, is the filename unique? Anyway,

**If you want to use LEFT JOIN in order to keep the lefts with a null value, use:**

```
SELECT DOCUMENT.filename FROM Xref XREF
LEFT JOIN Document DOCUMENT ON XREF.document_id = DOCUMENT.id
-- Filter by filename:
--WHERE DOCUMENT.filename = ? OR XREF
```

**Otherwise, I would suggest choosing INNER JOIN in order to get the matched rows:**

```
SELECT DOCUMENT.filename FROM Xref XREF
INNER JOIN Document DOCUMENT ON XREF.document_id = DOCUMENT.id
-- Filter by filename:
--WHERE DOCUMENT.filename = ?
```

**Result:** 
| filename | 
| D001     | 
| D002     |

SELECT * FROM - will result in displaying every column, you need to define what columns will be displayed on your new view.

**EDIT**
Regarding your comment, let's say you have two options for the input, you can use:

```
SELECT DOCUMENT.filename FROM Xref XREF
INNER JOIN Document DOCUMENT ON XREF.document_id = DOCUMENT.id
-- Filter by filename:
WHERE DOCUMENT.filename = ? XREF.id = ?
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this didn't retrieve anything...

Comment: Can you please describe what is the expected result? Also, pay attention to the WHERE condition and the way you use it.

Comment: Say I'm looking at "D001" from the Xref Table we can see it is linked to "X001". Therefore looking at filename "D001" I would expect to retrieve "X001". Thanks again.

Comment: I am not sure what is X001 because you don't have this ID but I guess it is the XREF.id. Once you join both tables together you can use the WHERE in order to filter and you can use OR to look on different columns.. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions are fine for a single-level search. If you want a multi-level search you can use a CTE, assuming there are no cycles in the data:

```
with
x as (
  select id, filename from document where filename = 'mydoc1.txt'
  union all
  select d.id, d.filename
  from x
  join xref r on r.document_id = x.id
  join document d on d.id = r.xref_id
)
select * from x;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, unfortunately this just retrieves the filename which I specify.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep documents that don't have a sub-document, then use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to get all main documents.

Also, I used a sub-select to link the sub-documents to the `xref` table, then linked that back to the main document query.

```
SELECT d1.id AS main_docid, d1.filename AS main_filename
    , s1.sub_docid AS sub_docid, s1.sub_filename AS sub_filename
FROM document d1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT x.document_id AS main_docid 
        , d2.id AS sub_docid
        , d2.filename AS sub_filename
    FROM xref x 
    INNER JOIN document d2 ON x.xref_id = d2.id
) s1 ON d1.id = s1.main_docid
WHERE d1.filename = ??????? /* Whatever filename you are searching for. */
```

If you want to search by a `sub_filename`, then change your `WHERE` statement to `WHERE s1.sub_filename = ???????`